# How to execute a menu item of a specific (external) application in Mac OS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How to execute a menu item (or, to obtain the menu items list) of a specific (external) application in Mac OS, like the 'Application Shortcuts' (in 'System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts') does?

I mean making an external application do a job by pointing to one of its menu item, just like what the 'Application Shortcuts'. I'm planning to write a program that can accomplish this job. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode you can set shortcuts in your `NSMenu` in `MainMenu.xib`.

Just add a new `NSMenuItem`, set the Key Equivalent in the **Attributes Inspector** and then finally use [Target-Action](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html) to connect it.

---

Sorry just saw that you wrote external application.

The application has to support this.
Most apple apps have support for AppleScript.

You can use this here to set up global hotkeys:

https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean, `Keyboard` in the preferences doesn't have any menu items

Comment: Apps that don't have an AppleScript dictionary may be controllable using UI Scripting. This includes the ability to choose menu items.

Comment: That's true, but UI Scripting may be buggy and is pretty time consuming